# Resume print but no extrusion

Tags: extrusion

Had a print stop about 20 % through and read through some old questions (3+ years) so I'm posting again.  Apologies if it's in here some where...

Found the layer to restart, deleted everything from layer 0 to layer 77 (in my case)

The set the E value to the value in layer 76, but still no extrusion.  Using Ultimaker Cura.  I can dump this but really want to know for future issues with larger prints...

*EDITED AFTER ANOTHER ATTEMPT:  (Same effect)
Sorry, I'm at a loss*
also made change to G92 code subtracting 5

Here is the start sequence:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:41644
;Filament used: 21.0489m
;Layer height: 0.2
;MINX:29.678
;MINY:92.227
;MINZ:0.2
;MAXX:198.806
;MAXY:194.503
;MAXZ:65.6
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 4.6.1
M140 S50
M105
M190 S50
M104 S200
M105
M109 S200
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
G92 E0
G92 E0
G1 F2700 E-5
;LAYER_COUNT:328
G0 Z15.6

G92 E1744.14148
;was G92E1749.14148

;TIME_ELAPSED:19808.769206
;LAYER:77
;TYPE:SUPPORT
G1 F2700 E1754.14148
G1 F1500 X73.481 Y110.942 E1754.14217
G1 X74.078 Y110.968 E1754.16204
G1 X74.527 Y110.792 E1754.17808
G1 X75.311 Y110.007 E1754.21498
```

Comment: You asked it to extrude 1.7 m of filament.

Comment: What is the purpose of those 19 non-printing moves?

Comment: Not sure Davo, I just cut out the layer detail, I can delete that also if it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

The line you added:

> ```
> G1 E1749.14148
> ```

asks the printer to extrude 1.7 **meters** of filament. The firmware likely has a feature to ignore such excessive requests as bogus. Then, subsequent extrusion amounts are also huge (1.7m+) relative  to the current extruder position (0) and also get ignored. What you meant to do was:

> ```
> G92 E1749.14148
> ```

which means "set the logical extruder position for its current physical position to 1749.14148 mm" so that subsequent extruder positioning commands are interpreted relative to that initial position.

Comment: added and edited op, same result though, unfortunately.  gears still not turning (checked just in case I had a clog)

Comment: I just noticed the `E-5` retraction just before the start - if not reversed, is going to prevent any extrusion from happening for a while. Could that be all that's happening? I would set the logical position to 5 less (1744) so that the first extrusion move also undoes the retraction.

Comment: so change G92 E1749.14148 to G92 E1744.14148?  Or could I just delete the E-5 line?

Comment: If you delete the `E-5` you should expect to see oozing all the way from the end of the prime line to the place where printing resumes. That's why I'd prefer doing it the way I suggested.

Comment: OK I'm sorry I know this is something I'm doing wrong.  changed the line and updated the op to current config and still no love.

Comment: Do you see the extruder trying to turn at all? Is the hotend at 200°C?

Comment: 200 degrees yes, extruder does not move at all, I can push manually through and filament passes like I'd expect, though.

Comment: he's operationg under `M82 ;absolute extrusion mode`, and sets the extruder to position 17-meters-something `G92 E1744.14148`, so subsequent extrusions should be higher than that.

Comment: @Trish: See edit history.